# Android Split Action Bar-icons only in the bottom bar

Tags: android-actionbar, android

I want to force the icons to be placed in the Bottom bar of Android's split action bar, while making sure that the top action bar remains empty. I have experimented a lot, but have not been able to figure out how to do this.

I am sure it is possible, because I have seen it in the Google Maps app. See the image below:

[split action bar with icons http://imageshack.us/a/img856/3592/portraito.png](http://imageshack.us/a/img856/3592/portraito.png)

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of what you are getting, and the menu XML resource that is giving you that result? A split action bar should put all its action items in the bottom bar by default, AFAIK.

Comment: As mentioned in developer.android.com, I have added this to the manifest " <activity
            android:name=".HomeScreenActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home_screen" 
            android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow">

Comment: @CommonsWare but even then no matter how many icons I add, all of them show up in the top action bar, here is the screenshot                             ![action-bar]http://imageshack.us/photo/myimages/337/actionbarsplit.png/

Comment: What device/emulator configuration is your screenshot taken from? It looks more like a `-large` than `-normal`. The split action bar is only used on `-small`/`-normal` screens in portrait orientation -- in all other cases, the action bar behaves normally without a split.

Comment: It is taken on a samsung galaxy tab2, I agree with you, but even when I added more icons then it could accommodate, even then the bottom action bar does not show up. And yes it is in portrait mode

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The split action bar is only used on `-small`/`-normal` screens in portrait orientation -- in *all other cases*, the action bar behaves normally without a split.

The Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 is a `-large` device. It will not use a split action bar, regardless of whether it is held in portrait, landscape, or is being stepped on by an elephant.

If you are seeing apps that run on such devices that appear to have split action bars, then they are not using the action bar for those items, but instead are rolling their own bottom bar. This is not advisable.

(note: no actual elephants were harmed in the creation of this answer)

Comment: Okay, many thanks. On another note, on adding too many icons to the action bar, this is what happens ![issue]http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/341/issue.png   . notice how the last icon shrank.

Comment: @3vikram: Do not use `always` for more than a couple of items. Use `ifRoom` for the rest, and those that do not fit will spill over into the overflow menu.