# Android menu on overflow BUT NOT not actionbar

Tags: android, menu, overflow, android-actionbar, visibility

any pointer as to how I could let my app running on android 3.0+ show the old menu ONLY on the overflow bar BUT not on the actionbar?

been trying to find this one out all over the web with no results!

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `showAsAction` attribute for `MenuItem` and set it to `never` to place the menu items in overflow menu.

Comment: Actually, I want my items in the overflow bar (at the bottom, next to previous, home & multitask) but NOT on the Actionbar. I don't want to see the three vertical dots (or anything else) there. It's a matter of the specific UI Design I'm following

Comment: You can try `android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"` in the `<activity>` element of your application manifest.

Comment: You can refer to this question -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12799059/android-split-action-bar-icons-only-in-the-bottom-bar

Comment: jai, don't see a link. Now I'm thinking on using some sort of UIActionSheet port to android. But If i can't find any good one I'd love keep getting input